Issue with Multilist Fields in Sitecore JSS
I am working on a Sitecore JSS task and facing the following issue:
I have added a rendering and its corresponding datasource.
The datasource has a multilist of vehicles, where:

Each vehicle has a multilist of variants
Each variant has a multilist of colors
In our UAT environment, the data appears correctly as expected.

Example:
fields:

vehicles: [{0}, {1}, {2}, ...]
variants: [{0}, {1}, {2}, ...]
colors: [{0}, {1}, {2}, ...]

However, when we moved to Production, the vehicles and variants are still fine, but the colors field shows as pipe (|) separated IDs instead of objects.
Example:
fields:

vehicles: [{0}, {1}, {2}, ...]
variants: [{0}, {1}, {2}, ...]
colors: itemid1|itemid2|itemid3

I need assistance in identifying the issue as there is information i need to fetch from the color objects and pass to the API.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Are you using GraphQL or Experience edge?

I would check that your color items are published

Maximum depth is controlled by the serializationMaxDepth setting defined in App_Config\Sitecore\LayoutService\Sitecore.LayoutService.config by default. When this value is reached it will stop expanding.
Check this setting and increase the value of this setting.
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1000593

To resolve this, you need to adjust the serializationMaxDepth setting in your Sitecore configuration. This setting controls the depth of the object graph that the Layout Service will serialize.
Here’s how you can patch this configuration:
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <layoutService>
        <serializationMaxDepth>2</serializationMaxDepth>
      </layoutService>
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Adding this patch ensures that the Layout Service in Sitecore correctly serializes the nested multilist fields up to the specified depth.

Nikita,
If you are checking in your Content Editor and the issue is in Master DB, and Item IDs are visible, which means the Colors have not made it to the Production Environment.
One of the two things would have happened:

The Color items created in UAT are different as compared to Production. Hence, when you moved all other items but thought Colors were already present on Production, it was not the case and hence, the Colors show IDs. To check this, you can check the Item IDs of the Color Items in UAT and compare them with Production to validate.
The Color items have not been moved yet, in which case the location where the color items are present would be empty.

If you are checking in Content editor, specifically in the Web DB and see this, I would suggest to publish the items (Republish with Children) from Master to Web DB to solve this issue.
Hope this helps!
